# Trying to pull json from URL, not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to pull a json file of products from a URL in PHP. I have the following code but it's not working. Can somebody please advise where I've gone wrong?

```
function getJson() {
$request = file_get_contents('https://3rdParty.guntrader.uk/ShootingSuppliesLtd/jsonGuns');
$json = json_decode($request);
return $json;
};

echo $json;
```

Undefined variable: json in C:\Users\darry\dev\VVV\www\ssheadless\importJson.php on line 36

Comment: I've changed the question.

Comment: Don't change your question. That invalidates the existing answers and the duplicate. If you have a new question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't call the method `getJson()`. Without calling a method the return value can't be accessed. Call the method.

```
function getJson() {
    $request = file_get_contents('https://3rdParty.guntrader.uk/ShootingSuppliesLtd/jsonGuns');
    $json = json_decode($request);
    return $json;
};

echo getJson();
```

Comment: Yep, $json is local variable, available only inside getJson() function. Not in global scope.

Comment: Of course, thank you.

Comment: I'm now getting 'Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string' does this mean an issue with the json format?

Comment: I've sorted it now, thanks for the help, new to PHP. I had to use print_r to view the contents of the array.